# Could not find my javascript classes built from Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browserify, qunit

### Situation

I am working on the frontsside of a webapp with typescript that I compile into JS. I want to run qunit test on the js that is generated. My typescript is merge  in one file using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) I want to run test upon my js object. I am runing the js without node in a tomcat webserver using a war package.

### Problem

I could not find the classes js that I have generated (problem of access or hidden object....) ? Animal class is not accessible when I try to use animal.js in a js script!? How to access this class in a js? **I want to run with no errors, animal.test.html.**

**animal.ts**

```
export class Animal {

    name:string;    

    constructor(name:string) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public run(){
        console.log('${this.name}:Animal runs.');
    }

    public eat(){
        console.log('${this.name}:Animal eats.');
    }

    public sleep(){
        console.log('${this.name}:Animal sleeps.');
    }
}
```

**animal.js** *(from animal.ts)*

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Animal.prototype.run = function () {
        console.log('${this.name}:Animal runs.');
    };
    Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
        console.log('${this.name}:Animal eats.');
    };
    Animal.prototype.sleep = function () {
        console.log('${this.name}:Animal sleeps.');
    };
    return Animal;
}());
exports.Animal = Animal;
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

**animal.build.js**

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var tsify = require('tsify');

browserify()
    .add('src/test/typescript/animal.ts')
    .plugin(tsify, { noImplicitAny: true })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function (error) { console.error(error.toString()); })
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

**Build run command**
I use node with browserify as referenced in the [typescript lang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html) site

```
node animal.js >  src/test/typescript/animal.js
```

**animal.test.js**

```
QUnit.module( "Form test" );

QUnit.test( "hello test2", function( assert ) {
 var a = new Animal("toto"); 

  assert.ok( a!==undefined && a!=null);
});
```

**animal.test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.23.0.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.23.0.js"></script>
  <script src="animal.js"></script>
  <script src="animal.test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Qunit response** 
[image: qunit animal ko!]

Comment: Wow, is it the browser that translates JS errors to French? That's certainly impractical.

Comment: arf. sorry. this is done in chrome. He says : "Reference Error : Animal is not defined" My problem is that even loading the animal.js in a html page, I can't use Animal class !

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access `window.Animal` but it's certainly not there. You need another JS/TS file that you should use with QUnits but don't include in development/production code:

`test_main.ts`:

```
import {Animal} from './animal';
window.Animal = Animal; // or global.Animal = Animal
                        // I don't know if browserify converts
                        // "global" to "window" or not.
```

Now replace `.add('src/test/typescript/animal.ts')` with `test_main.ts`.

---

## What was wrong?

If you are using ES6 export/import modules, that means you are using "CommonJS" module system. When you use `tsify`, Typescript code is converted to node-compatible JS code. Then you use `browserify` to convert node-compatible JS code to browser compatible JS code. Browser doesn't support CommonJS module system natively. So "browserify" tries to mimic it and that's why you need to provide it a single entry point.

There are other solutions to your problem, e.g. you can write your unit tests in TypeScript or in node world. If you did that, you would access `Animal` class using `import` statement.

It's a complicated topic for beginners, I would suggest you to learn what CommonJS is and how browserify/webpack etc. converts it into browser code.

---

Comment: I understood the work around provided in order  to perform my test. By Will have to build another ts in order to import as a global variable. Thanks.

Comment: You can write your tests in node.js and use browserify to convert it to browser. According to https://github.com/kof/node-qunit/blob/master/readme.md you can run QUnit tests in node.js too.